# Double List Item insertion in JTextPane

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, htmleditorkit

I have a button that inserts an unordered list item into a [`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html). However, when I click on the button to insert a list item, two bullets are inserted instead of one. One bullet is inserted only during the first time insertion.

I cut out the functionality from my application and pasted the code into a small SSCCE (below) and the problem remains. Does anyone have any idea as to what might be happening here?

[The problem has been solved, below is the complete solved code. There are two ways to do this, refer to the functionality in the show and the bullets button]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.ElementIterator;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class Main {

    private static Button2 show = new Button2 ("Show"); 
    private static LIButton bullets = new LIButton("Bullets", HTML.Tag.UL);
    private static JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                create();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void create() throws HeadlessException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        pane.setContentType("text/html");
        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(bullets);
        panel.add(show);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class LIButton extends JButton {

        static final String LI_HTML = "<HTML><BODY><UL><LI></LI></UL></BODY></HTML>";

        public LIButton(String name, HTML.Tag parent) {
            super(new HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction(
                name, LI_HTML, HTML.Tag.UL, HTML.Tag.LI, HTML.Tag.BODY, HTML.Tag.UL));
        }
    }

    static class Button2 extends JButton implements ActionListener {

        static final String LI_HTML = "<HTML><BODY><UL><LI></LI></UL></BODY></HTML>";

        public Button2(String name) {
            super(name);
            this.addActionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) pane.getDocument();
            HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) pane.getEditorKit();

            try {
                kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength() - 1, LI_HTML, 0, 1, null);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've never been able to understand how to add HTML, but I would guess that your text string should not contain HTML and BODY tags, but only the text/tag for the list item?

Comment: So true! And the Javadocs don't make it any bit easier. I have modified the code above to include the solution.

Comment: trashgod's solution makes more sense then your posted solution. As I already suggested, it does not make sense to insert a string containing the HTML and BODY tags. Only the original text string should contain those tags. Insertions to the Document should contain on the new tags you want to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below seems to work.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class Main {

    private static LIButton bullets = new LIButton("Bullets", HTML.Tag.UL);
    private static JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                create();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void create() throws HeadlessException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        pane.setContentType("text/html");
        pane.setText("<HTML><BODY><UL></UL></BODY></HTML>");
        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(bullets);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class LIButton extends JButton {

        static final String LI_HTML = "<LI>item</LI>";

        public LIButton(String name, HTML.Tag parent) {
            super(new HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction(
                name, LI_HTML, parent, HTML.Tag.LI));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found an alternate way. Please refer to the 'show' button in the above example (which has been edited to reflect the solution)